# Store data model into Flutter Secure Storage

Tags: flutter, serialization, flutter-secure-storage

How do we store model data to flutter secure storage... or does it supports it?

I have a model like this... I load data from my API to this model... once I have data, I wanted to save it to the flutter secure storage and vice versa(load entire data to model from flutter secure storage)...

```
class MyUserModel {
    MyUserModel({
        this.authKey,
        this.city,
        this.contact,
        this.email,
        this.isContact,
        this.userId,
    });

    String authKey;
    String city;
    String contact;
    dynamic email;
    bool isContact;
    int userId;
}
```

Of course, I know we can read and write data like below... I am just checking if there is a way where we can directly write it from the model...

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

// Create storage
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read value 
String value = await storage.read(key: key);

// Write value 
await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
```

I saw hive supports this feature out of the box but I realized that it takes little time (2-3 sec) for initialization also Author is working on an alternative to hive due to two major blocks... the new database called [Isar](https://github.com/isar/isar) which clears all roadblock but it is still in development...

if it is possible then please share the sample code...

Answer (score 15):

to save the object:

> 1. convert your object to map with `toMap()` method
> 2. serialize your map to string with `serialize(...)` method
> 3. save the string into secure storage

for restoring your object:

> 1. deserialize secure storage string to a map with `deserialize(...)` method
> 2. use `fromJson()` method to get your object

by that, you will serialize your data into a string and save and retrieve them.

```dart
class MyUserModel {
    String authKey;
    String city;
    String contact;
    dynamic email;
    bool isContact;
    int userId;

  MyUserModel({
    required this.authKey,
    required this.city,
    required this.contact,
    required this.email,
    required this.isContact,
    required this.userId,
  });

  factory MyUserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) =>
    MyUserModel(
      authKey: jsonData['auth_key'],
      city: jsonData['city'],
      contact: jsonData['contact'],
      email: jsonData['email'],
      isContact: jsonData['is_contact'] == '1',
      userId: jsonData['user_id'],
    );
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(MyUserModel model) => 
    <String, dynamic> {
      'auth_key': model.authKey,
      'city': model.city,
      'contact': model.contact,
      'email': model.email,
      'is_contact': model.isContact ? '1' : '0',
      'user_id': model.userId,
    };

  static String serialize(MyUserModel model) =>
    json.encode(MyUserModel.toMap(model));

  static MyUserModel deserialize(String json) =>
    MyUserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(json));
}
```

Usage:

```dart
final FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

await storage.write(key: key, value: MyUserModel.serialize(model));

MyUserModel model = MyUserModel.deserialize(await storage.read(key: key));
```

Comment: Nice and perfect solution... Saved my time a lot...

Comment: Is this really working `static MyUserModel deserialize(String json) => MyUserModel.fromJson(json);` is sending a String to *.fromJson that in the method description is awaiting for a Map<String, dynamic> this will not work.

Comment: @1020rpz sometimes the answer is just giving an idea of how you could fix the issue, btw the answer has been updated.

Comment: This is a super-useful code snippet, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by encoding your Model into json saving it in `Secure Storage` and then decode the json and get the model back.

```
// Saving model into Storage
static Future<void> setMyUserModel(MyUserModel user) async {
  await const FlutterSecureStorage().write(
    key: 'user', value: user.toRawJson());
}

// Getting model from storage
static Future<MyUserModel> getMyUserModel() async {
  return MyUserModel.fromRawJson(
      await const FlutterSecureStorage().read(key: 'user') ??
          '{}');
}
```

And of course you need to implement `fromRawJson()` and `toRawJson()` inside your model.

Sorry for the late reply :P.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, encode your model into JSON and store it in secure storage. Later, decode the JSON to retrieve the model.

```
 final storage =  FlutterSecureStorage(); 
static const String modelData = "modelData";

// Saving model into Storage
static Future<void> setModel(user) async {
  final jsonDataEncoded = jsonEncode(jsonData);
    await storage.write(key: modelData , value: jsonDataEncoded);
}

//call this when you want to store your data to secured storage
 ClassName.setModel(decodedResponse);//decode your json and send it here

//to read data from the local storage || secured storage
static Future<MyModel> getDataFromLocalStorage() async {
    final jsonModel = await storage.read(key: modelData);
    final jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonModel.toString());
    final items = List.from(jsonData);
    dataList = items.map((e) => MyModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return dataList;
  }
```