# How do I save session cookie from response in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Let's say I log into an api with my flutter app. In an website, they automatically store the login cookie and then can use it. But in flutter app, how do I store the cookies and session?  And how do I pass that into post to let the api know I have a valid login session?

Comment: check https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store model data into Flutter Secure Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253148/store-model-data-into-flutter-secure-storage)

Comment: But how do i extract the cookie from response?

Comment: 1) The "standard" way to access cookies is to embed some Javascript in your HTML.  Perhaps this is an option for you.  2) For Flutter, you have (at least) two challenges: a) programmatically reading the cookie, and b) persisting it to local storage.   SUGGESTION: start here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Cookie-class.html or here: https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/How-do-i-set-Cookie-to-Http-Request

Comment: It"s making me more confused,  i just want the part to extract cookie and how to use it. I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: It's making me more confused, I just want the part to extract
> cookie and how to use it.

There are a number of complexities, depending on exactly what you ultimately want to do.

But let's assume:

- Your Flutter app makes an HTTP request (GET, PUT, etc.)
- The server (e.g. your Flask app) returns cookies in the HTTP response (in the HTTP response header).
- Let's further assume your HTTP code looks something like [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data):

  ```
  Future<http.Response> fetchAlbum() {
    return http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
  }
  ```
- In that case, you *should* be able to reference the [cookies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpResponse/cookies.html) property of the Response object returned from the server.

SUGGESTION: See also these links:

- [Flutter For Web Cookie/Token Sessions and Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66582220/421195)
- [Add Session Support to Flutter with Flutter Session](https://medium.com/swlh/introducing-session-to-flutter-6b6354ec6ade)

Answer (score 3):

When you make a post request using HTTP package `import 'package:http/http.dart';` it will return you Response object, use `headers['set-cookie']` property to get cookies. Keep in mind that `headers['set-cookie']` can have more than 1 cookie. They will be separated by a COMMA ONLY, there are no spaces between them.

Example:

```
String cookies = getCookiesFromSecureStorage();
final response = await post(
  Uri.parse('your-url-here'),
  body: data,
  headers: {
    'cookie': cookies
  }
);

if(response.headers['set-cookie'] != null) {
  // save/process cookies
  String rawCookies = response.headers['set-cookie']!;
}
```

NOTE: You can't simply take 'set-cookie' as a string and reuse it in the next post call. You have to process the received cookies. The below function will parse rawCookies and return a dictionary of Cookie objects. Use that dictionary to remove/invalidate expired/deleted cookies. For example: sometimes a server might return a cookie with the `deleted` value, you should not send it back.

```
Map<String, Cookie> parseCookies(String value) {
  Map<String, Cookie> cookies = {};

  final regex = RegExp('(?:[^,]|, )+');
  Iterable<Match> rawCookies = regex.allMatches(value);
  for (var rawCookie in rawCookies) {
    try {
      if(rawCookie.group(0) != null) {
        final cookie = Cookie.fromSetCookieValue(rawCookie.group(0)!);
        cookies[cookie.name] = cookie;
      }
    } on Exception {
      // the cookie might be invalid. do something or ignore it.
      continue;
    }
  }

  return cookies;
}
```

This is how you would parse cookies back from Cookie objects to String and send them back to the server:

```
 static String getHttpCookiesAsString(Map<String, Cookie> cookies) {
   List<String> rawCookies = [];
   cookies.forEach((key, value) {
     rawCookies.add("${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}");
   });
   return rawCookies.join('; ');
 }
```

Comment: I just find an error in your last code, it should be:
`cookies.forEach((name, cookie) {
  rawCookies.add("$name=$cookie");
});`