# HttpClient looses Session cookies

Tags: php, flutter, dart

i have a php Server, that (on a certain request) sets `$_SESSION['user']`.

In my Flutter App i use a single `HttpClient` that i store in a static variable:

```
static String serverUrl = 'https://myServerURL.de';

static HttpClient client = HttpClient();

static String query(String f, Map<String, String> d, Function(dynamic) callback) {
  String args = d.entries.map((e) => '&${e.key}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}').join('');
  String url = '$serverUrl/sql.php?f=$f$args';
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
      .then((HttpClientResponse response) => response.transform(new Utf8Decoder()).listen((response) {
        var res = jsonDecode(response);
        callback(res['data']);
  }));
  return '';
}
```

the request that sets `$_SESSION['user']` works fine (I can tell by the response i'm getting), but if do another query, my Server responds, that `$_SESSION['user']` is not set. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check this [How do I save session cookie from response in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73720765/19577100) it might help

Comment: sorry i still don't get it

Comment: Dart (read Flutter) doesn't store cookies(SESSIONS) by default like Browsers do. You have to receive->store->send cookies yourself. In short: when you make a request to the server, PHP(in your case) will create a `SESSION ID`, it will then return this ID to you in the form of a cookie. You then have to send this `SESSION ID` back to the server so it can identify you. Once again, browsers do it by default. In Flutter, you have to do it yourself.  It's a complex topic, but I hope this gives you some insight into what to look for.